# Osclass Phone number in Database

Tags: php, jquery

I use the RingCaptcha Plugin,
when you enter the number this get in the s_phone_land in the database!

I make a new field in the database s_phone_verified
in the plugin i change the file ring_captcha/index.php

```
Params::setParam('s_phone_verified', $user_phone);
```

In the oc-includes/osclass/frm/User.form.class.php i add the line

```
static public function phone_verified_text($user = null) {
  parent::generic_input_text("s_phone_verified", isset($user['s_phone_verified'])? $user['s_phone_verified'] : '', null, false);
}
```

But still it do not save it in the database!

What do i need to change more?

Thanks